# Is this the proper behaviour for event filter and requstfocus in javafx?

Tags: javafx, navigation, keycode

I have a very simple task to accomplish. I just want to press any letter on a button, matches the key code, and move the focus to a text field. I wrote
a simple test code as shown. I have no problem to shift the focus. However,
I don't want the letter I press shows up in the text field. Seemingly a simple programming solution turns out to be not so simple.

I don't understand why the event consume method doesn't stop the event from propagating down the event chain and have the typed letter shown up at the text field.

It seems like after the requestFocus is called, the text field picks up the letter typed from the button. This happens on Mac. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
package testkeynavigation;


public class TestKeyNavigation extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    TextField txt1 = new TextField();
    TextField txt2 = new TextField();
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt1);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt2);
    root.getChildren().add(vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);


    btn.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) ->{
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
            e.consume();
            System.out.println("e.isConsumed: "+e.isConsumed());
            txt2.requestFocus();
        }

    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    btn.requestFocus();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what the order of event propagation is, but this works if you use a `keyReleased` handler instead of a `keyPressed`. It also works with `keyTyped` (but you have to change the check on the key to check the character typed instead of the code - keyTyped events do not have a key code).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Seems very strange that keyPressed and keyReleased behave so differently.

Comment: Internally, the text field (or, more accurately, its behavior class, which is buried deep in private API) uses a listener for some kind of key event in order to "know" that text has been typed in it. It could be implemented using any of a `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, or `keyTyped` event... If it doesn't happen to be implemented to listen for `keyPressed` events, consuming them will make no difference to the behavior of the text field. So this isn't really a consequence of how the events work; it's a consequence of how the text field is implemented.

Comment: I see. However, logically, you will think keyPressed event should be catched before keyReleased event.

Comment: My point is that the text field has no need to listen for a key pressed event at all. It just has to respond to *one* of those events.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify my response. You see the key pressed event happens on a button. Yes, text field has no need to listen for a key pressed event on a button. That is why this behaviour is SO strange that the text field will respond to a key pressed even that is not even originated from it.

Comment: Actually... I think you just answered this question, didn't you? :).

Comment: Key events are passed to the node which has the keyboard focus. If you press & release a key, then three events are generated: pressed, released, and typed. In your code, you listen for a key pressed event on the button, and if it occurs you consume the key pressed event and transfer focus to the text field. The key release happens subsequently to that, so when the key released event occurs, the text field has focus and receives that event, which is not consumed (the key *pressed* event was consumed). So the text field detects that a character was typed.

Comment: I see. Very succinct explanation. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think in my mind I was thinking that after a key pressed event occurs on a button, and if I moved a focus away from a button, the sequent key released and key typed events would be cancelled. Apparently, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three kinds of key event: `KEY_PRESSED`, `KEY_TYPED`, and `KEY_RELEASED`. In a key stroke, an event of each of these types is fired, in that order, to the UI node that has the keyboard focus at the time of the event.

A `TextField` has an internal listener for `KEY_TYPED` events; so if a `KEY_TYPED` event occurs when the text field has focus, a character is entered into the text field (or other actions occur, e.g. deleting characters or moving the caret, depending on the key).

In your code, you listen for the first one of these - `KEY_PRESSED` - to occur on the button. If the key press has a code of `A`, you consume *that* event (the `KEY_PRESSED` event) then transfer keyboard focus to the text field. At a slightly later moment, the user releases the key, and since the text field now has focus, a `KEY_TYPED` event is fired on the text field. Note that this is a new event, so it is not consumed, so the text fields reacts as though a character has been entered. Finally, a `KEY_RELEASED` event is fired on the text field.

You can see this in action if you add the debugging code:

```
txt2.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> {
    System.out.printf("Key event on text field: type=%s, code=%s, character=%s%n", 
            e.getEventType(), e.getCode(), e.getCharacter());
});
```

To fix the problem, just listen for the last event in the series of events: the key released event. Note that you don't need to consume the event.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    TextField txt1 = new TextField();
    TextField txt2 = new TextField();
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt1);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt2);
    root.getChildren().add(vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);


    btn.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) ->{
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
            txt2.requestFocus();
        }

    });

    txt2.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> {
        System.out.printf("Key event on text field: type=%s, code=%s, character=%s%n", 
                e.getEventType(), e.getCode(), e.getCharacter());
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    btn.requestFocus();
}
```