# Why requestFocus doesn't work in KeyReleased in javafx?

Tags: javafx, navigation, keycode

[My last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212844/is-this-the-proper-behaviour-for-event-filter-and-requstfocus-in-javafx)

In my last post, thanks James for answering my question. However, I still don't quite understand why, after I change KeyCode.A to KeyCode.DOWN, the keyboard focus is shifted to txt1 instead of txt2?

The code seems very straight forward to me. By releasing a down arrow button, the button's setOnKeyReleased method catches such specific event and calls the txt2.requestFocus() method to shift the keyboard focus to the text field txt2. Unless I miss anything here, I don't see why the focus will be shifted to txt1 instead.

Anyone any idea?  I test this code on Mac.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
      }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    TextField txt1 = new TextField();
    TextField txt2 = new TextField();
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt1);
    vbox.getChildren().add(txt2);
    root.getChildren().add(vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);


    btn.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) ->{
      if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) { //<---MAKES THE CHANGE FROM
                                         //KeyCode.A TO KeyCode.DOWN
        txt2.requestFocus();
      }
    });

    txt2.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> {
       System.out.printf("Key event on text field: type=%s, code=%s, 
         character=%s%n", 
         e.getEventType(), e.getCode(), e.getCharacter());
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    btn.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: I suspect what's happening is that the down key event is being intercepted by the "normal" keyboard focus navigation: you'll notice that if you comment out all your key handling, the behavior remains. Not sure about a workaround....

Comment: In general, changing the built-in behavior of JavaFX controls is pretty difficult; the behavior classes at the time of writing are private API and the behavior is pretty much baked-in. That may change in a later release.

Comment: So I *think* the keyboard navigation here is handled by a `KEY_PRESSED` handler on the scene: basically if that event with the down key pressed bubbles all the way up to the scene, then the scene moves the focus to the "next" control. (TextFields consume the arrow key presses because they use them for caret positioning.)  Since the scene transfers the focus when the key is pressed, the `KEY_RELEASED` event never reaches the button. So (in contrast to your previous question :) ), if you change this event back to a `KEY_PRESSED` handler, and consume the event, it will do what you want.

Comment: I noticed that. The strange thing is that if I put the focus on txt1 and then press the down arrow key, nothing happens. It seems that the "normal" keyboard navigation does not work on text field.

Comment: Yes... TextInputControls (such as text fields) have their own handlers for those keys, which move the cursor around the text. (Specifically, `DOWN` will move to the end of the text in a text field, and to the next line down in a text area.) So those events on a text field are handled before they reach the scene.

Comment: James you are right. If I use keyPressed instead of keyReleased, the program will work. I think Oracle should come up with some sort of fix to make the codes behave more consistently, and more intuitive. Like in this case, a key released event happens on a button should never be caught by a text field.

Comment: I think the response from Oracle right now would be that the behavior is intended to be "baked-in" and not open for modification. At some point the behavior classes will become public API, at which point the "correct" approach to this would be to write a new behavior (or subclass an existing one) for the controls of interest. It sort of makes sense: for "low-level" key stroke events, such as keyboard navigation of the focus cycle, a key pressed event is the appropriate one. For text controls though, it makes sense to think about "typed characters", so key typed events are more appropriate.

Comment: In my opinion, when `.setOn<Event>` doesn't work, simply add the handler as a filter via `.addEventFilter()`. That may not help for production codes, but at least it helps in troubleshooting.